# How to fix ' table Students has no column named student_name'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am still new to SQL and databased programming and all...
I am having an issue with adding a student's info to my data base adn keep getting the table Students has no column named student_name Error.

Here is the part of the file that is related to the adding of the student's data in the db.

```
import sys, sqlite3, time

class DBHelper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn=sqlite3.connect("studentDatabase.db")
        self.c=self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Students(Name TEXT,grade TEXT,\
                        DOB TEXT, Parent1_name TEXT, Parent1_phone TEXT, Parent1_email TEXT, \
                        Parent2_name TEXT, Parent2_phone TEXT, Parent2_email TEXT)")

    def add_student(self, student_name, grade, dob, parent1_name, parent1_phone, parent1_email, parent2_name, parent2_phone, parent2_email):

        self.c.execute("INSERT INTO Students (student_name, grade, dob, parent1_name, parent1_phone, parent1_email, parent2_name, parent2_phone, parent2_email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(student_name, grade, dob, parent1_name, parent1_phone, parent1_email, parent2_name, parent2_phone, parent2_email))
        self.conn.commit()
        self.c.close()
        self.conn.close()
```

Comment: `CREATE TABLE Students(Name,` ... and then you do `INSERT INTO Students (student_name,` - seems obvious together with the error message!

Comment: Although you use PyQt5 as you point it out, the problem is the sqlite part, so to remove unnecessary complexity from your problem you should not place the PyQt5 part

Answer (score 1):

In the `CREATE TABLE` statement, there is no `student_name` column defined. There is a `Name` column defined; change that to `student_name` and that error shouldn't occur.